# Need to find the nearest time baser on Current time

Tags: iphone

I want to find the nearest time from an array with the comparison  of current time.(i.e) if the current time is 10:00 am in this case there is an array it have 9:00am,9:50am,9:30am.
from this i want to get the 9:50am. How can i achieve this? and i don't want to change the index value of the object in the array.

Answer (score 2):

parse the array comparing each value with the current time, store the delta of seconds between the time in the array and the current time and the index of the value in the array. the check if the next one has a smaller time delta and is yes ovveride the value and the index. at the end of the parsing you have the index of the closest timestamp and the time delta.

doing

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 3600*24; // just a big number
NSUInteger indexOfDate;
// I didnt checked if the delta can be negative in this case think aboud absolute number

for (NSDate * date in dateArray) {

      if(abs([date timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]]) < interval) {
           interval = abs([date timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]]);
           indexOfDate = [dateArray indexOfObject:date];
            }
      }
```

Comment: Hi Nicolas Manzini
   I want to get index value of the nearest time of the current time what i have to do for that. As I mentioned in my question.Can you plaese guide me.

Comment: array have 2:00am,5:00am,4:00am the current time is 5:30am now i want to get the index value of 5:00am how can i do this.

Comment: I think you will need to turn to nsdateformatter. It can turn any nsdate to a string like 5 am or 19 min or a full date. look at the function dateFromString from an nsdate formatter. you can compare date easily with nsdate and turn those ns date to actual days and hour with nsdateformatter

Comment: sorry Nicolas Manzini instead of getting 5:00am i'm getting 2:00am. Now i want to get the index value of 5:00am

Comment: did you try to record the difference of time  as absolute value maybe the interval is negative and negative number are always smaller. I just added the abs

Comment: I didn't understand Nicolas Manzini. Please explain me what to do?